# insert array in a underscore/lodash chain

Tags: javascript, underscore.js, lodash

I'm trying to create an array in a lodash/underscore chain, but it doesn't work.

Example :

```
  var foo = _.chain(currentValue) // let's say "1,2,4"
                .split(',')       // now it is [1,2,4]
                .max()            // now it is 4
                .tap(function(maxValue) {
                  return _(Array(maxValue)).fill(false);
                }) // should be now [false, false, false, false] but doesn't work
                .value();
```

What I am missing ?

Comment: Though i never use lodash or whatsoever I would try `Array(maxValue)` instead of `_(Array(maxValue))`.

Comment: I think `tap` is not doing anything with your return statement. I think its just giving you the opportunity to mutate the value. Since strings are immutable, this is probably not a use case for `tap`.

Comment: Yes I misunderstood tap here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) `_.tap` is mutate argument, it is better to use `_.thru`

2) to get result of chaining you must call `.value()` at the end of chain

3) so my proposal

```
_.chain('1,2,4')
    .split(',')      
    .max()           
    .thru(function(maxValue) {
        return _.chain(maxValue).times(_.constant(false)).value();
    })
    .value();
```

and if really no need `_.tap` or `_.thru`

```
_.chain('1,2,4')
    .split(',')      
    .max()           
    .times(_.constant(false))
    .value();
```

Answer (score 3):

You can that using [`_.times()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.2#times), and `_.fill()`:

```js
var currentValue = "1,2,4";

var foo = _.chain(currentValue) // let's say "1,2,4"
  .split(',') // now it is ["1","2","4"]
  .max() // now it is "4"
  .times() // [undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined]
  .fill(false) // [false, false, false, false]
  .value();

console.log(foo);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.2/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

And without lodash using ES6's [`Array#from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from#Using_arrow_functions_and_Array.from):

```js
const str = "1,2,4";

const result = Array.from({ length: Math.max(...str.split(',')) }, () => false);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is pure js solution for this.

```js
var str = "1,2,4";

var result = Array(Math.max.apply(null, str.split(','))).fill(false);
console.log(result)
```

Comment: It is less readable with pure Javascript than Lodash version. Moreover, some function may miss to Javascript, even if it is not the case for the example.